# How is co-operative play made more difficult in the Something Wicked expansion for A Touch of Evil?

Tags: a-touch-of-evil

I have read in the [description of the Something Wicked expansion](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/42047/a-touch-of-evil-something-wicked#description) for A Touch of Evil on BoardGameGeek that the expansion contains additional rules that include "expanded challenge for cooperative play," but I don't see the rules posted in the files section. We've had a fairly easy time at beating the base game co-operatively and so I'm curious what changes in a co-op game with this expansion. A different shadow track? Bonuses for the Villain? More frequent mystery cards?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer. But here's a [detailed review](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/453399/by-the-pricking-of-my-thumbs-a-new-expansion-t). And here's a [rules summary](http://www.headlesshollow.com/downloads/games/ATouchofEvil_v2.pdf), including the new expansion on the last page. I think what you really want to see is the Advanced Mystery Phase Chart, which sounds like it makes the game a lot more challenging. But that doesn't seem to be online anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Flying Frog Productions seems to be very worried that people will not buy their expansions if the post the rules for them. With that being said, what the most likely mean by, "expanded challenge for cooperative play," is that a new [Advanced Cooperative Mystery Phase Chart](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/707803/a-touch-of-evil-something-wicked-expansion?size=medium) is rolled on (2d6) versus the old chart (1d6 - quoted below) before drawing and reading the Mystery Card.

> 1 Darkness Falls - The Shadow Track immediately moves 2 Steps closer to Darkness. The Heroes may collectively take 5 Wounds divided as they see fit to prevent this.
>
> 2 Creeping Shadow - The Shadow Track immediately moves 1 Step closer to Darkness. The Heroes may collectively take 3 Wounds divided as they see fit to prevent this.
>
> 3-4 Minion Attack! - Roll once on the Villain’s Minion Chart and place that Minion at a Random Location.
>
> 5-6 Scattered Clues - Draw a Random Location and place 2 Investigation in that space.